# Asynchronous REST services testing with SoapUI

Tags: rest, asynchronous, mocking, soapui, asynccallback

I'm attempting to use SoapUI (5.0.0 beta) to test a RESTful web service which issues asynchronous responses to a supplied Callback URL.

So far, I am able to invoke the service and confirm the initial synchronous response received. I have also created a 'REST MockService' that issues an appropriate response to the callback received from the server, and I supply the endpoint for this as the Callback URL in the initial request.

What I am now struggling with is creating a test case that ties the two together such that I can 'expect' the asynchronous callback before proceeding to another step in my test case. I tried adding a 'Mock Response' Test Step to my test case following the initial request. However, this just yields an unhelpful 'Missing SOAP Operations to Mock in Project' error message. I took a brief look at the SoapUI source for this error message and discovered the method returning the error is first checking if I am using a WSDL interface. Why I would be doing so with a REST project is beyond me, but there you have it!

Appreciate any guidance on how to proceed!

Comment: So that i understand this..you are able to place a request and receive a response; In the request you send a call back URL; You also have a mock service;In the synchronous request you give the mock service's endpoint URL as the call back URL. So essentially you send a request to the server, it response something (i assume saying request received) and in turn reaches out to the mock service for processing. This mock service returns a response to the server...What does the server do with this request?

Comment: You are pretty much on the money. The response returned to the server by the mock service is largely inconsequential - it just needs to return a 200 OK or 204 No Content. Everything works, except that I cannot easily validate this since I cannot easily tie the two occurrences together in the test case assertions.

Comment: I would need more details but speaking based on available information you would need to use a JDBC or a groovy step to verify the response received. This would be based on what the server does with the mock response. Also, you are correct a normal test step assertion will not work in this case.

Comment: Perhaps my last comment was slightly confusing - I don't need to do any validation of what is returned to the server by the mock service. I just need to include an assertion in my test step that the server made the callback to the mock service. Anyway, will see what SmartBear comes up with in a future release of SoapUI, and I'll work around it with some hacky scripting for the moment!

Answer (score 0):

Having logged a query on the SoapUI Community Board, it seems there is currently not a good mechanism for achieving this, but my query has prompted an enhancement request at least!

http://forum.soapui.org/viewtopic.php?f=5&t=23697